# Can Mountain Lion take a sleeping Mac and write the RAM to disk after a timeout?

Tags: macos, sleep-wake, hibernate

Is it possible to configure OSX Mountain Lion to go from suspand-toRAM to suspend-to-disk after certain amount of minutes?

The default sleep mode seems to be suspend-to-RAM until the battery is almost empty. This makes it troublesome for traveling with the laptop as the battery is guaranteed to go to empty after closing the lid and putting your computer to the bag for a day or two.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the `pmset` man page,

> hibernatemode = 3 (binary 0011) by default on supported portables. The
>        system will store a copy of memory to persistent storage (the disk), and
>        will power memory during sleep. The system will wake from memory, unless
>        a power loss forces it to restore from disk image.

But then also

> standby causes kernel power management to automatically hibernate a
>        machine after it has slept for a specified time period. This saves power
>        while asleep. This setting defaults to ON for supported hardware. The
>        setting standby will be visible in pmset -g if the feature is supported
>        on this machine.
>
> standby only works if hibernation is turned on to hibernatemode 3 or 25.

(which it is by default on supported portables)

> standbydelay specifies the delay, in seconds, before writing the hibernation image to disk and powering off memory for Standby.

On my machine, with settings that I believe are default, when I type `pmset -g |grep standbydelay` I get the result of 4200, meaning that after 70 minutes of sleep, the machine cuts power to the memory and restores from the memory image saved to the hard drive.

If your settings do not look like this, the `pmset` command just might be your new friend.

Comment: What kind of machine do you have and does `pmset -g | grep standby` return 0 or 1? On my 2011 MacBook Pro running 10.8.1, I have 0 with a delay of 4200 (I haven't changed these). I could be wrong, but I believe this feature is disabled by default for non-SSD Macs (since they take so much longer to wake from disk).

Comment: I have a MacBook Air, and on my machine, it returns 1.